# Unexpected tooltip behaviour in UserControl

Tags: c#, activex

I am creating a ActiveX control in C# 2.0. I want to show tool Tip over my User Control. So I define a property and also add a Tool Tip control on my user control.

```
public string ToolTipText
{
    get { return this.myToolTipText; }
    set
    {
        this.myToolTipText = value;
        this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this, this.myToolTipText);
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Everything is fine here.
When I set ToolTipText from another application which using this control, it shows the tool tip on mouse over.

But suppose if I click once on my control, then tool tip not visible on mouse over. Do I have to define mouse Over event on my user control?

Comment: isn't that a default behaviour for tooltip?

Comment: thanks,
default behavior is when ever you mouse over any control it should show the tooltip.

Or suppose if you go to any other control then come back to previous one then it should shows tooltip.

i think it need to change some focus events.